# window.print onclientclick preventing onclick in codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, code-behind

I have a page that needs to do a postback via OnClick to the page after window.print() is called. I have spent a couple of hours looking for a solution, but so far haven't found the right combination. I set up a test page to make sure there was no other javascript interfering. Here is the code

`<asp:Button ID="Print" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick = "window.print();return true;" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="Print_Click" />`

```
protected void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Write("Clicked");
}
```

That is the rendered button as in the browser:

`<input id="Print" class="button" type="button" onclick="window.print();return true;__doPostBack('Print','')" value="Print" name="Print">`

The postback is not happening and the print_click is not being called. I have also tried adding the onclientclick in the code behind on page_load

I would appreciate any help- I think I have looked at 100+ search results.
Thanks,
Judy

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Print" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick = "window.print();return true;" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="Print_Click" />

Comment: <input id="Print" class="button" type="button" onclick="window.print();return true;__doPostBack('Print','')" value="Print" name="Print">

Comment: @JDandChips any Solution?

Comment: @Brainiac other than the one I posted as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Button ID="Print" runat="server" Text="Print" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="Print_Click" />
```

Have you tried removing the `OnClickClick` to see if the postback is triggered correctly without this?

If this works then I would try adding the clientside print manually:

```
var originalClick = $('#Print').click();

$('#Print').click(function(){
   window.print();
   originalClick();
});
```

I think the `protected` level is fine, but maybe try `public` just in case.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I just tried that and it triggered the code behind, which is what I had found out earlier by removing the onclientclick. Here is what I put in the head section of my page. Sorry this might not come through as a code snippet.<script type="text/javascript">
        var originalClick = $('#Print').click();

        $('#Print').click(function () {
            window.print();
            originalClick();
        });
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem here was with Firefox. A colleague gave me code that was a little different and it didn't work in FF, but it works in IE and Chrome.
Here is what he gave me- part of it involved hiding the 
        function handlePrintClick() {
            window.print();
            var buttonId = "<%= Print.ClientID %>";
            var buttonElm = document.getElementById(buttonId);
            buttonElm.click();
                }

Comment: grr.. I still can't figure out how to format the code!